# How to integrate Huawei Mobile Services (HMS) in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase, huawei-mobile-services

I've found a lot of guidelines on how to integrate HMS in my apps. But majority of them are different or using android studio. May I know which one is the latest guidelines to integrate HMS in my apps for Unity.

Also, I want to enable In-App-Purchase (subscription) for my apps as well.
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED**

Currently I'm trying to implement In-App-Purchase for huawei. Huawei tech said that users need to signIn first before they can use IAP. But I received this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUcqJ.png) while testing signIn

How to obtain product info ? [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HriZw.png)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you have two main options:

- [UDP SDK from Unity](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201245867969240162&fid=0101187876626530001), which is the Unity official solution to HMS in Unity. However has been under maintenance for some days now.
- [Unity HMS Plugin from EvilMinds](https://github.com/EvilMindDevs/hms-unity-plugin), an open source alternative that is already functional and includes supports to more HMS kits. Looks pretty promising for the future.

In any case you can still manually access HMS Android SDK directly using [Unity SDK Android API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UnityEngine.AndroidJNIModule.html).

Comment: Currently, I'm using the second option which is Plugin from EvilMinds. But for me the guidelines is not very clear. I'm stuck at few things.

Comment: For example. https://github.com/EvilMindDevs/hms-unity-plugin

Point number 4. There's no HMSManager.

Comment: Yes docs are not up to date, I would recommend you see the demos themselves, they are more clear.

Comment: Actually I can't use their demo as well. I still get the same error with my *UPDATED* question.

Comment: @SyedBob Its a null reference. Please re-check your variables in the IAP. :)

Comment: @shirley you mean IapManager ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Unity provides the HMS Plugin [here](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/add-ons/services/huawei-hms-core-app-services-176968): Unity Asset Store > Huawei HMS Core App Services

The **README** file contains information about development guides, API references. For more technical questions, please submit a ticket with Unity Customer Service.

2. Currently Unity does not support the In-App-Purchase (subscription) function. It will be planned in the future.

**Update:**

For the IAP error:
It is a null pointer. Please check for unassigned objects. If you cannot find anything, please delete project and install again cause sometimes these kind of things happening.

Comment: thanks for your reply but i can't access Intergration Handbook link.

Comment: @SyedBob Yes, this site requires permission.

Comment: How to get permission ?